# Прошу помощи в регулярке

Tags: php, json

Проверял в онлайн сервисах - всё замечательно: выделяется именно то, что нужно, а вставляю в парсер - выходит ошибка:

```
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: 
Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in
```

Вот из чего нужно вытащить название картинки:

```
"kind_id":"76","storage_type":"0","color":"#990099","quality":"3","time_expire":"0","image":"\/images\/data\/artifacts\/kolco_nekr_vol_11.gif","picture":"
"kind_id":"76","storage_type":"0","color":"#3300ff","quality":"2","time_expire":"0","image":"\/images\/data\/artifacts\/ring_b_crit_11_20080414.gif","picture":"
```

Вот так выглядит парсер:

```
$re = "/\\\"kind_id\"[^\"]\\\"76\\\"\\,\\\"storage_type\\\"\\:\\\"[0-9]+\\\"\\,\\\"color\\\"\\:\\\"\\#[0-9a-z]+\\\"\\,\\\"quality\\\"\\:\\\"[0-3]+\\\"\\,\\\"time_expire\\\"\\:\\\"[0-9a-z]+\\\"\\,\\\"image\\\"\\:\\\"\\\\(?)[^\"]images\\\\(?)[^\"]data\\\\(?)[^\"]artifacts\\\\(?)[^\"](.*?).gif\\\"\\,\\\"picture\\\"\\:\\\"/si";
$str = "\"kind_id\":\"76\",\"storage_type\":\"0\",\"color\":\"#990099\",\"quality\":\"3\",\"time_expire\":\"0\",\"image\":\"\/images\/data\/artifacts\/kolco_nekr_vol_11.gif\",\"picture\":\"\n\n\"kind_id\":\"76\",\"storage_type\":\"0\",\"color\":\"#3300ff\",\"quality\":\"2\",\"time_expire\":\"0\",\"image\":\"\/images\/data\/artifacts\/ring_b_crit_11_20080414.gif\",\"picture\":\"\n\n\n\"kind_id\"[^\"]\"76\"\,\"storage_type\"\:\"[0-9]+\"\,\"color\"\:\"\#[0-9a-z]+\"\,\"quality\"\:\"[0-3]+\"\,\"time_expire\"\:\"[0-9a-z]+\"\,\"image\"\:\"\\(?)[^\"]images\\(?)[^\"]data\\(?)[^\"]artifacts\\(?)[^\"](.*?).gif\"\,\"picture\"\:\"";

preg_match_all ($re, $str, $matches);
```

Помогите пожалуйста, `preg_match_all` не работает, а `preg_match` находит, но выводит только первое найденное слово...

Comment: Ну ведь JSON же...

Comment: в смысле?) я что то не то делаю ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php вам этот json в массив превратит и спокойно берите из него вашу картинку

Comment: @Qwertiy, слишком просто, to автор - а перевести ошибку пробовали? *Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash*

Comment: @Константин жесть конечно ты костыли придумываешь. `$array = json_decode($content)` - получишь массив твоих значений. `print_r($array);` получишь свой массив со всеми данными

Comment: preg_match_all не работает не выводит данные, а preg_match выводит только первую картинку а вторую не хочет )) в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ideone.com/ynohn0

```
<?php

$data = readline();
$data = json_decode($data);

echo $data->image;

echo "\n\n";
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: извините ничего не понял ) для чего это и как с этим работать

Comment: @Константин, это вместо регулярки.

Comment: )) я понял что это вместо регулярки , но не понимаю как , куда что б работало ... спасибо что помогли..

Comment: Всё равно немного не пойму, данные меняются , там не постоянно одни и те же цифры, буквы... и картинок там несколько в самом коде, регулярка уже работает но не хочет выводить по `preg_match_all`

Comment: @Константин у Вас структура данных - JSON, поэтому Вам и предлагают парсить текст как JSON, что более правильно, чем писать регулярку в данной ситуации

Comment: Все это можно записать в одну строку и будет выглядеть значительно проще регулярок: `(json_decode($text))->image`